# How can I get a route using dynamic parameters in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I'm new to Laravel. I have a route defined in routes.php

```
Route::get('article/{id}/{slug}', array('uses' => '....', 'as' => '.....'));
```

How can I get it using `route()`? I'm trying this, but failed.

```
<a href="{{ route('article', $article->id, $article->slug) }}">
```

Answer (score 1):

I just got a solution using `as` and array parameter.

```
Route::get('article/{id}/{slug}', array('uses' => '.....', 'as'=>'article'));
```

Then, call it from `route()`.

```
<a href="{{ route('article', array($article->id, $article->slug)) }}">
```